# Rails size of "third level" members

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models:

Region, Society, Member - and they go like this:
Region has many Societies & Society has many Members

How do I get size of members related to region - say Region1 has 100 members (which are each in their own societies).

I am pretty sure i would need a scope...

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use a `has_many :through` association, like so:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :societies
  has_many :members, through: :societies
end

class Society < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :society
end
```

Now you can do something like `@region.members.count` to get the total number of members for a region.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I was already thinking about going this way. I do have another question though....what about the migrations? Do i need to add any new columns, like member_id or something? Thanks again!

Comment: Tried without any table modifications and on my great surprise it just works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine this is the fastest way to do this, but this should work with your current setup:

```
Region.first.societies.inject(0){ |result,s| result += s.members.count }
```